# void declaration error

Tags: arduino-uno

I am new to Arduino and C++ and I was practicing with a traffic light project.

This is my code:

```cpp
int red = 10;
int yellow = 9;
int green = 8;

void setup() {
  pinMode(red,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(yellow,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(green,OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  changelights();
  delay (15000);
}

void changelights{
  // 1st action: green off to yellow
  digitalWrite(green, LOW);
  digitalWrite(yellow, HIGH);
  delay (3000)
  // 2nd action: tellow to red 
  digitalWrite(yellow, LOW);
  digitalWrite(red, HIGH);
  //3rd action: caution light 
  digitalWrite(yellow, HIGH);
  delay (3000)
  //4th action: caution to go 
  digitalWrite(red,LOW);
  digitalWrite(yellow, LOW);
  digitalWrite(green, HIGH);
}
```

I tried compiling it and returned an error message that said that I did not declare my "changelights" function. What should I do to fix this?

Thank you very much

Comment: I recommend to put only 1 instruction in 1 line. that improves readability by a lot and makes it easier to find errors.

Comment: You forgot the parentheses `( )` for the parameters after the definition of `changelights`. You need these, even if you don't provide any parameters. Though this is a pure C/C++ syntax question, thus I'm voting to close. Fixing such problems doesn't help any other people, thus I'm always helping in the comments and then vote to close.

Comment: Missing semi-colons after the `delay(3000)` calls.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to put the parenthenses `()` after the name of the function `changelights`. They are there to declare variables you can use later in the code like that:

```cpp
void function(int a){
  a+=1;
  return a;
}
```

To fix your error just change

```cpp
void changelights{
```

to

```cpp
void changelights(){
```

Keep in mind if you want to program C++ (which would be Off-Topic here, but you mentioned it in your question) you have to declare the function in the beginning or mention it.

Comment: The Arduino IDE takes care of adding the forward declarations for you.

Comment: The problem is with the missing parentheses at the function definition. The forward declaration of the functions is done by the Arduino IDE. And I think we can assume, that he uses it. At that point working with Arduino that is the simplest way.

Comment: @chrisl I see, I will edit the answer.